# How to convert Reveal Module Pattern in JavaScript to Typescript when function is taking global as argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I am rewriting(code refactoring) the Javascript code into Typescript. I face a problem when converting reveal module Pattern into typescript namespace.
The only thing that I don't understand is the role of *global* here. I really don't know what this *global* means here.

//My Javascript Code

```
 var TPS = (function(global)
    {
    var met = {
        supported: TPSSupported,
        isCalledDNMatchesTPS: isCalledDNMatchesTPS,
        isTPSReady: isTPSReady,
        isActiveCall: isActiveCall
}
        return met;

    })(this);
```

//My solution

```
  namespace TPS {
     export let met = {
            supported: TPSSupported,
            isCalledDNMatchesTPS: isCalledDNMatchesTPS,
            isTPSReady: isTPSReady,
            isActiveCall: isActiveCall
            }
    }
```